# How do rewrite underscore to dash without mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using [php-login.net](http://php-login.net) as a model MVC framework for my site.

However, the view/controller setup only works for URLS with underscores:

`domain.com/this_is_a_subdir`

Current SEO best practice suggests using hyphens as separators, as google does not recognise underscore as a separator:

`domain.com/this-is-a-subdir`

If one attempts to use dashes (`-`), then it results in an Internal Server error 500.

I am told that this is because the first and second part of a url represent the class/controller name and the according method/action. And in PHP classes and function names cannot have dashes in them.

Advice [here](https://github.com/panique/php-login/issues/404) suggests to use either mod_rewrite or to use "the parameter as the content URL, like wordpress etc do".

I'm interested in how the latter of these solutions would work, could someone explain what this would involve/where I might start?

Comment: Have you try naming methods with underscore and accessing them with hyphens in url? I think MVC handles this themselve.

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes, it doesn't work.